# wordpress child theme not working

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

i am new to word press now i am working on wordpress child theme. now i am going to creat child theme of " Chulavista " theme.

i just creat a sub directory and creat file with name of style.css

in my style.css just place this code

```
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*
Theme Name: chulavista Child
Theme URI: agilesoft.us
Description: Chulavista  child Theme
Author: Agilesoft
Version: 1.3
License: GNU General Public License
Template: chulavista
Tags: 
*/





@import url("../chulavista/style.css");
```

its simple. but when i activate child theme the layout font and header will be change and show recent post, meta, and category in top menu div.

i can't understand this behaviour. because when i activate parent theme it will be correct.

Please help me out of this problem...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com. SO is for programming questions.

Comment: I think you should place the style header at the top of the file for WP to see it. Before anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Child theme is an individual theme which relies on the Parent's theme files. When you activate the Child theme, you have to set the `Appearance` settings for the theme. Similar to what you do while activating another Parent theme.

Note that the layout font might be changing due to the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your `style.css` is correct, your problem is something else.

I will assume that you are working on a *Linux Environment*.

If you want to install custom themes manually copying your theme directly in the `wp-content/themes` folder, be sure you create a *symbolic link* for it as well:

Example:

```
sudo ln -s /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/your_theme/ /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/themes/your_theme
```

I had the same problem as you and I fixed it by creating the *symbolic link*. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Does Chulavista support child themes? If it hasn't been written with child themes in mind, it might not properly support them. e.g. if it uses [get_template_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) instead of [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri). Check the functions.php and header.php files in the Chulavista theme to see if that is the case.